# How to allow a user to log into a website and save their username information in PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, hidden

I am trying to create a website where a user logs in or creates a new account if they are not already a user. I have that working, but what I cannot seem to figure out is how to have PHP or HTML save the username through different pages. A user logs in, and then based on the specific user, my website will show different exercises the user has completed in the past, as well as allow the user to add more exercises in the future. My website uses PHP, HTML, and MySQL to search different tables in my database and output the results.

I have tried many different possible solutions, such as sessions in PHP like this, but it did not work. Each PHP page has this at the beginning:

`session_start();`

and then further down, I have:

```
$_SESSION["Username"] = $_POST['Username'];
```

I have also tried hidden input values in HTML, but that did not seem to work quite right either. Each HTML page has this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Username" value="Cbartowski">
```

I have tried a lot of ways to try to have my web page save the username and use that data throughout my pages, but I haven't had any luck. Would sessions in PHP be the way to go? Or hidden input in HTML? Or something else entirely?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$_SESSION` should work, why doesn't it?

Comment: You did it the write way. You need an HTML input which is sent to your PHP. Maybe you are writing the $_SESSION variable for every call (even when you are not sending the data) to your page and for this reason your variable value is always empty (overwritten with a null value)

Comment: sessions are definitely the easiest way to proceed to maintain user state between pages. Using `$_SESSION["Username"] = $_POST['Username'];` on every page that does not use POST to send this information will simply overwrite the session variable with duff / null information so only use that after submitting the form the first time

Comment: All:  I am using $_SESSION on every page. Maybe that is why it isn't working because I do not have information being sent on every page but I still have the $_SESSION everywhere.

But that leads to another issue: How would I use the $_SESSION variable in an SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP session\_start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015729/php-session-start)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using hidden input to store the username is a critical threat to your website.
One can easily check out the username of the person by viewing the source code.

**Using PHP sessions is the way to go here.**

What i have understood is that you are initializing

```
$_SESSION["Username"] = $_POST["Username"];
```

on every page. Now, consider you have two php pages.
One is **form-request-handler.php** and other is **display-user-preferences.php**

Now, when user submits the form the username gets set into session variable using the above code snippet on form-request-handler.php page.

Now, when user hits the display-user-preferences.php page, you again set the value of session variable. But since, no post request has been made to this page so Null is get saved into session variable and you are not able to retrieve the required information from the database.

So, whichever php page is handling the post request just initialize your session variable there and use it on other pages.

Sessions variables will be available to you unless you call

```
session_destroy();
```

Hope, this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

html hidden input is not a good way because users can see it with the browser show source action.
are u shure session file are saved and the session ID is include in your links ?
if not sessions start a new session each time the user click a link.
have a look in your temp folder each time your clicking a link; if a new session file is created it's because you forget the session ID.
maybe it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your form method : Should be POST
- Check your variable using:

`var_dump($_POST['Username']);`

Answer (score 0):

So from experience, its better to use post methods when doing user authentication. Purely for security reasons. In addition to this, using PHP's session variables is also the recommended way of passing user information from one page to another. 
if you want to store the user name in the session variable, here are some steps you can follow

- start the session using `session_start();`
- name the session variable and store the information you want 
  `$_SESSION['what-ever-you-want-to-call-it']=$what-you want to store`
  eg.`$_SESSION['Username']=$_POST['Username']`. Note the use of single quotes
- You can now call `$_SESSION['Username']` anywhere in a php script provide the session has been started before calling it. That is `session_start();`.

**Note** break apart the code your working on and ensure each individual piece works. eg,is the post providing you with the username??