# comparing session variable in where clause in mysql select query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hye developers, please sort me out, I have two php files, in the first file (login.php) I declared a session variable $_SESSION['email']; and assigned user input into it, and in the second file, I place a select query and use that session variable to compare a database column in the where clause of the query, but the session variable is reporting undefined index in the index.php file

I actually want the query to check if the database column is marthar then echo some html elements

login.php

```
    $email = '".$_POST['email']."';
    $_SESSION['email']=$email;
```

email is the name of my html input

index.php

```
    <?php
                $query=mysqli_query($db_handle,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if(is_array($row)){
    if($row['model']=='Marthar'){

    echo "<li>
    <a href='settings.php' class=' hvr-bounce-to-right'><i class='fa fa-cog nav_icon'></i> <span class='nav-label'>Settings</span> </a>
    </li>"; 
   }
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Your session is not starteed in index.php Do a search gor session_start() it is widely dsicussed on SO See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015729/php-session-start and
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `login.php`, please use the below and add `session_start();` on top of  your php page

```
$email="";
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { 
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
} else {
    $email='';
}
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `session_start()` to the top of the second file. That should make the session variable available.

Comment: I add session_start(); function at the first php block in index.php

Answer (score 0):

add

```
session_start();
```

on top of your index.php and login.php

change

```
 $email = '".$_POST['email']."';
```

to

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
```

add `var_dump($_SESSION);` in login and index php to make sure that sessions are set and values are there. And add `var_dump($_POST);` to your login as well

Comment: its all there sir

Comment: add those things and see if anything changes.

Comment: really appreciate sir, did that still undefined index, the 'var_dump(SESSION);'  add some errors, I had to remove it

Comment: your code also work, the problem is from me in the first place, I keep refreshing the page instead of filling the login form again