# How to call PHP case from another PHP case

Tags: php, jquery

I have been using a formula to uniquely secure id's gathered from database before they are presented to the client.

However, as my code grown complex, I've fallen into this pitfall: I have two separate cases returning json that need to use the same id. Because my securing function produces a unique hash and key at each perform, hashed ID gathered from one case cannot be encrypted in the other one that needs to use it. Therefore as a solution, I thought that sending hashed id gathered from first case back to first case again, decrypt it there and then somehow pass it to the other case without client never having chance to catch the real id.

All the codes work fine, my problem is matching the id drawn from first case that is to be used in the second case that also sends data back before case break, which is simply a client-triggered loop. I am providing codes in case you would ask it. The problem is simply matching the same id with different unique hash in two separate php cases. Sorry if I made this more complicated than it should have.

- This is the first case I am using for filling a dropdown select.

  ```
          case "tutorRefresh":

          $tutorSelectSql = "SELECT id, tname, tsurname FROM tutors";
          $tutorSelectQry = pg_query($tutorSelectSql);

          while($row = pg_fetch_array($tutorSelectQry)){

              $id = lockPandoraBox($row['id']);//encrypt the id
              $response[] = array("id" => $id,
                                  "tname" => $row['tname'],
                                  "tsurname" => $row['tsurname']);

          };

      if(isset($response)){

      echo json_encode($response);

      } else {

      $response = array("val" => 0);
      echo json_encode($response);

      }

      break;
  ```
- This is the function used by the second case that updates the table data, since it is too long and complex for a single issue to post it all here, I only shared relevant part of the code. I have to match the id encrypted in above code with the one encrypted here since this code fills in the table while the code above just fills in the dropdown select.

  ```
      $crypted = lockPandoraBox($row["appid"]);
      $tutorID = lockPandoraBox($row["tutorid"]);//encrypting id
      $clientID = lockPandoraBox($row["clientid"]);//same method for another id, ignore this.

      $fApp["hours"][] = array("recId" => $crypted,
                               "hour" => $row["hour"], 
                               "tutor" => $tutorArr["tname"]." ".$tutorArr["tsurname"],
                               "tutorId" => $tutorID,// id that I need to use
                               "client" => $clientArr["cname"]." ".$clientArr["csurname"],
                               "clientId" => $clientID,
                               "department" => $dept,
                               "degree" => $deg,
                               "purpose" => $purposeArr["pname"],
                               "purposeId" => $row["purpose"],
                               "contact" => $clientArr["cgsm"],
                               "email" => $clientArr["cemail"],
                               "tutorAbsCheck" => $tutorAbsArray["id"],
                               "tutorAbsReason" => $tutorAbsArray["reason"],
                               "clientAbsCheck" => $clientAbsArray["id"],
                               "clientAbsReason" => $clientAbsArray["reason"]
                               );
      /*  */
  }


  return json_encode($fApp);
  }
  ```
- Lastly, this is the code in my main page which works in click event function that triggers the event I need. It simply changes select box's selection for the matching clicked record. It picks the id from table and tries to match it with the id in select box. Thanks in advance.

  $("#tutorEdit").val(dayData["hours"][$(el.currentTarget).attr("key")].tutorId).trigger("change");

Comment: i have read just first two paragraphs and thought - maybe you are looking for session variables?

Comment: would be, I didn't know about them at all. I'll check it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015729/php-session-start

Comment: Honestly, this seems unnecessarily complicated.  Why are you encrypting these ids at all? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: I want to encrypt them to make them useless in case any malicious script is run on the page tries to mess with my javascript. Furthermore, I just don't want to trust clients with id's.

Comment: @AdamK. I already use sessions, I didn't know if session variables are something else I should check. I'm still reading about it.

Comment: Well this might, or might not help you... In my project after logging in, i create a loginhash, that the user uses in combination with username to validate himself. Server also checks the IP. In case the IP changes, the loginhash gets revoked and user has to login again. (And it expires after some time of inactivity) (also i have added a two phase login validation, that new IP has to be whitelisted via email)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to change the structure a bit to combine both cases in order to achieve my goal. I wanted to know if I could get around it.