# Login in page not redirecting to index.php after entering correct details with no error displayed

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I'm developing a login system for my website using php 7. The login page redirects to index.php when i use the following code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

But fails to redirect to index.php or any page when i use

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
```

I use !isset to make sure a user does not go direct to a page by typing its url on the browser. This is to ensure you get redirected back to the login page to avoid unauthorized access in the admin panel. But it is rather not logging in even when correct details are entered.

LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('../inc/db.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,strtolower($_POST['username']));
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

    $check_username_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $check_username_run = mysqli_query($con, $check_username_query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_username_run) > 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_username_run);

        $db_username = $row['username'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        $db_role = $row['role'];

        $password = crypt($password, $db_password);

        if($username == $db_username && $password == $db_password){
            header('Location: index.php');
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['role'] = $db_role;
        }
        else{
            $error = "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
    }
    else{
        $error = "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/circleda.png">
    <title>Login | Amasiatu Admin</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">


 <form class="form-signin animated shake" action="" method="post">
  <div class="login-logo" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 18px">A</div>
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Amasiatu Login!</h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">

  <div class="checkbox ">
    <label>
      <?php
     if(isset($error)){
         echo "$error";
     }
     ?>
    </label>
  </div>

  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted year">&copy; 2018-2019</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php require_once ('inc/top.php'); 

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

     <?php require_once ('inc/header.php'); ?>

       <div class="container-fluid body-section">
           <div class="row">


               <div class="col-md-3">
                 <?php require_once ('inc/sidebar.php'); ?>
               </div>


               <div class="col-md-9">
                   <h1><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard <small style="color: #495057">Statistics Overview</small></h1><hr>

                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                      <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard</li>
                      </ol>
                    </nav>

                    <div class="row tag-boxes">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="panel panel-blue">
                                <div class="panel-heading">

                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            <i class="fas fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-xs-9">
                                            <div class="text-right huge">11</div>
                                            <div class="text-right">New Comment</div>
                                       </div>

                                   </div> 

                                </div>
                                <a href="">
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <span class="float-left">View All Comments</span>
                                        <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="panel panel-red">
                                <div class="panel-heading">

                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-5x"></i>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-xs-9">
                                            <div class="text-right huge">20</div>
                                            <div class="text-right">All Posts</div>
                                       </div>

                                   </div> 

                                </div>
                                <a href="">
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <span class="float-left">View All Posts</span>
                                        <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                                <div class="panel-heading">

                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            <i class="fas fa-users fa-5x"></i>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-xs-9">
                                            <div class="text-right huge">41</div>
                                            <div class="text-right">All Users</div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div> 

                                </div>
                                <a href="">
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <span class="float-left">View All Users</span>
                                        <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="panel panel-green">
                                <div class="panel-heading">

                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-5x"></i>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-xs-9">
                                            <div class="text-right huge">8</div>
                                            <div class="text-right">All Categories</div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div> 

                                </div>
                                <a href="">
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <span class="float-left">View All Categories</span>
                                        <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div><hr>

                    <h3>New Users</h3>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SN #</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Role</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Val Amasiatu</td>
                                <td>Computacity</td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Val Amasiatu</td>
                                <td>Computacity</td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Val Amasiatu</td>
                                <td>Computacity</td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Val Amasiatu</td>
                                <td>Computacity</td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Val Amasiatu</td>
                                <td>Computacity</td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View All Users</a><hr>

                    <h3>New Posts</h3>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SN #</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Post Title</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Views</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Learn Python and build a Complete Project</td>
                                <td>Video Tutorials</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-eye"></i> 35</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Learn Python and build a Complete Project</td>
                                <td>Video Tutorials</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-eye"></i> 35</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Learn Python and build a Complete Project</td>
                                <td>Video Tutorials</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-eye"></i> 35</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Learn Python and build a Complete Project</td>
                                <td>Video Tutorials</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-eye"></i> 35</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>18 Jan 2019</td>
                                <td>Learn Python and build a Complete Project</td>
                                <td>Video Tutorials</td>
                                <td><i class="far fa-eye"></i> 35</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View All Posts</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>


    <?php require_once ('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: _Note:_ Don't use `crypt()` for password hashing. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. They are specifically made for password hashing and will give you stronger hashes.

Comment: Its $_SESSION, Am trying to login, not post a data to be stored in database. My code works if i remove isset and not !isset

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in your `inc/top.php`? If not, the session you previously set won't be loaded and you will check against an empty session. You should also add a `exit;` after any `header('location: ...');` to stop any code after from executing.

Comment: <?php require_once('../inc/db.php'); 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="icon" href="img/circleda.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-admin.css">

    <title>Amasiatu | Admin</title>

Comment: I have added session_start(); to the code and everything worked like magic. So grateful. Thanks.

Comment: How do i give u upvote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP session\_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015729/php-session-start)

Comment: No need for up votes. IMHO, this question should be closed as a duplicate since this question already has been asked and answered many many times here before.

Comment: How do u mean by possible duplicate of session_start();

Answer (score -1):

Highly likely some output is being given to unlogged user in "inc/top.php".
Try this:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require_once ('inc/top.php'); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
?>
```