# Guessing Game in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, methods

I have been having some issues with my PHP code, more specifically being that I am attempting to create a guessing game that allows for more than one attempt on the same random number, but at the moment it only resets and does not track attempts.

I have attempted to add a while-loop and a do-while loop around the if statements inside of the PHP section to no avail, with all that happens being 5 instances of any given message appearing. I believe it may have to do with the ending to my HTML but I have not been able to solve this after hours. I apologize if there is a similar answer somewhere else; I have searched and found nothing. Thank you for any advice given.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="p-5 text-center">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Number Guessing Game</h1>
</div>

<body class="container">
<div id = "change">

    <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $randNum = rand(1, 10);

        $guessNum = " ";
        
            if ($randNum == $_POST["num"]) {
                echo "<p class='userCorrect'>Correct!</p>";
            } else if ($randNum > $_POST["num"]) {
                echo "<p class = 'userLow'>Too low; please try again! </p>";
            } else if ($randNum < $_POST["num"]) {
                echo "<p class = 'userHigh'>Too high; please try again!</p>";
            }
    }
    ?>


    <form method="post">
    <div class="text-center" id="margin">
    <p>I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10.</p>
        <p>Guess a number (1-10):
        <label>
            <input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="10" autofocus>
        </label></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Guess" class="button">


</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would need to either make use of a database (with proper user registrations of some sort), or JavaScript's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Addition to @ObsidianAge 's answer: you could use [sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015729/what-is-php-session-start) to store temporary (until you close your browser). [Official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

Without a session, cookies or database PHP does not remember your intial random number, and always generates a new one.

To work around this, you need to use sessions.

That means starting the session as mentioned by [Definitely not Rafal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2409484/definitely-not-rafal) and checking if you already wrote something into it,

```
  session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['rand_num'])){
        $_SESSION['rand_num'] = random_int(1, 10);
    }
    $randNum = (int)$_SESSION['rand_num'];
```

Complete code below, with a little type safety added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guess a Number</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="p-5 text-center">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Number Guessing Game</h1>
</div>

<body class="container">
<div id="change">

    <?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['rand_num'])){
            $_SESSION['rand_num'] = random_int(1, 10);
        }
        $randNum = (int)$_SESSION['rand_num'];
        $guessNum = (int)$_POST['num'];

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
            if ($randNum === $guessNum) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Correct! Try again?</div>';
                $_SESSION['rand_num'] = random_int(1, 10);
            } else if ($randNum > $guessNum) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Too low; please try again!</div>';
            } else if ($randNum < $guessNum) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Too high; please try again!</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>


    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-center" id="margin">
            <p>I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10.</p>
            <p>Guess a number (1-10):
                <label>
                    <input type="number" name="num" min="1" max="10" autofocus>
                </label></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Guess" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, as mentioned in another comment, the ideal solution for anything more complex than this would be a database or javascript and AJAX and a database.

I also strongly recommend you to look into the MVC pattern, since this php in html inclusion can get messy really fast.

Here's a few links that would help with that:

- [MVC starter](https://r.je/mvc-tutorial-real-application-example)
- [Working with databases](https://symfonycasts.com/tracks/php)
- [Working with databases alternative](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners)
- [Bringing structure to plain PHP and a starter for Frameworks](https://r.je/mvc-tutorial-real-application-example)
- [Javascript for PHP devs](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/javascript)